# Sorting Datarows using any dataColumn

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a following datatable with 3 columns.

[image]

I want to sort the datatable rows on the basis of 2nd column.(with header E)
Is there any built in function do this?

i tried..

```
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
    dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: why not dt.DefaultView.Sort = "E Asc";

Comment: @HatSoft: it didn't work..Btw what does `dt.AcceptChanges();` do?

Comment: dt.AcceptChanges will commits all the changes made to the table. aah msdn also say that it must be called after attempt to update is made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort a datable by column

```
 dt.DefaultView.Sort = "E Asc";
```

**Else this way**

```
string[] names = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    names[i] = dt.Rows[i]["E"].ToString();
}
Array.Sort(names);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows[i]["E"] = names[i];
}
```

Also `dt.AcceptChanges` will commits all the changes made to the table. aah msdn also say that it must be called after attempt to update is made

> **Remarks from MSDN**
>
> When [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx) is called, any DataRow object still in edit mode
>   successfully ends its edits. The DataRowState also changes: all Added
>   and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed.
>
> The AcceptChanges method is generally called on a DataTable after you
>   attempt to update the DataSet using the DbDataAdapter.Update method.

Comment: I tried your code. It made some changes in the order but it didn't sort it perfectly.

Comment: what sort of sort do you want, i mean by sort by just 1 column or more

Comment: i need datarows wrt 2nd column: for ex. 4,6,8,25,48,78 but it sorts like 25,4,48,6,48,8

Comment: may i ask whats the type on column E

Answer (score 7):

Probably the easiest (and most powerful) way is to use `Linq-To-DataSet` and [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
var tblOrdered = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<int>("E"))
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you cannot use Linq, you can use [`DataView.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx):

```
DataView view = tbl.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "E ASC";
```

But that uses a `DataView`, the original `DataTable` is unsorted.

So if you need the table, you could use [`DataView.ToTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx):

```
tbl = view.ToTable();
```